# Cannot implement a close button for Wikitude SDK 4.0

Tags: ios, wikitude

I am new to this also and I have found some great help here but not for this problem. I am building an app with a Wikitude SDK 4.0 that has a built in scan function. I am trying to implement a close button into the ScanViewController without success. The App works fine as requested, the scan works fine but cannot get back to the app. I know this must be a stupid question but please help, I am going crazy! What am I doing wrong, I really want to understand this.

This worked in an earlier version with Wikitude SDK 3.3 but not 4.0.

I am using:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 75)];
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
[button setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(userDidPressCloseButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)userDidPressCloseButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Close");    
    UIViewController *closeScanner = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainPage"];
    [self presentViewController:closeScanner animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: @Nicopico, Merci my friend but I still have a blank screen and no Close button. I have made sure the VC has a storyboard of MainPage and also the scan button is IBAction with touch up inside. This is driving me nuts lol.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to destroy the World instance before pressing the back button. it will not freeze the app.

one more thing you are presenting the view controller in one line and in next line you are dismissing that view controller.